# Passing select result as argument

Tags: postgresql

For the function [notify](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-notify.html).

How can the payload be passed as argument obtained from a select?

The following does not work:

```
notify tweet, (select text from datastore.tweet limit 1)
```

> [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "("

Comment: have you tried removing the brackets and exchanging them with a single-quote? 
`notify tweet, 'select text from datastore.tweet limit 1'`

Comment: @iLuvLogix that would pass the query as a string instead of its result

Comment: have you tried `(SELECT text FROM datastore.tweet LIMIT 1).*`

Comment: @JSpratt tried now, same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using the `NOTIFY` keyword I believe you can do this:

```
SELECT pg_notify('tweet', (SELECT text FROM datastore.tweet LIMIT 1)::text);
```

or if you don't need the result you can use `PERFORM` like so:

```
PERFORM pg_notify('tweet', (SELECT text FROM datastore.tweet LIMIT 1)::text);
```

There is an example like this in the docs [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-notify.html).

Comment: This will fail with `query has no destination for result data` when used inside a trigger function. Solution is to use `PERFORM pg_notify('tweet', (SELECT text FROM datastore.tweet LIMIT 1)::text);` instead.

Comment: I'll add that as an alternative solution.